別のxamlファイルのコントロールを参照したい
プログラミング初心者です。
Visual Studio 2019 CommunityでWPFアプリ（.NET Core）をC#で作ろうとしています。
MainWindow.xamlに記述したbutton1のbutton1.IsMouseOverを
Page1.xaml.csから参照するにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。
こちらにも投稿しています。
https://teratail.com/questions/lidjivyg7mcliv

解決しました。
var w = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
他のサイトで教えていただきました。
